# Why are some JavaScript methods executable and others are not?

Tags: javascript, function

I was wondering why some of the method calls on strings (`.length`, `.toUpperCase()`, etc.) don't take parentheses at the end of the call and others do.

Is it that methods such as `.toUpperCase()` are actually changing the variable's value where methods such as `.length`, are just reporting information about the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't have parentheses on the end, it's a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), not a method.

`.length` is a property that returns the length of an array or string.

`.toUpperCase()` is a method that makes all of the letters in a String object uppercase.

You are right about the difference between "reporting information" and "changing the variable's value": that's the difference between properties and methods. Methods perform actions and properties are a piece of information about an object.

Answer (score -1):

It's just design decisions, and every language I've ever written in has these dilemmas (and usually some inconsistencies therein). Should string manipulation be in-place? Should things like `length` be a property or a method? Etc... There's no simple answer, so it usually varies between languages and often even within a language.

To be clear, every method in JavaScript is executable, it's just that some are methods while others are properties, and you need to know which is which.

Comment: Why was this downvoted twice within the first 30 seconds of being posted?